# django get media url in view function

Tags: python, django

Serve Media File in view function

View.py

```
file_path = Tracks.objects.get(pk=event_id)
name = file_path.file.name
fullpath = os.path.abspath(name)
```

When i perform above function, the fullpath is throwing below error :

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ri/studio/videotube/uploads/2014/10/15/Wildlife_512kb_hVnnOc2.mp4'
```

But the actual file live in `file:///home/ri/studio/videotube/videotube/site_media/media/uploads/2014/10/15/Wildlife_512kb_hVnnOc2.mp4`

This is my media root `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")`

What should i do for getting media url in view function ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can access to your settings variables by:

```
from django.conf import settings

your_media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

But you can also access to the file path as the same way you get the name:

```
name = file_path.file.name
url = file_path.file.url
path = file_path.file.path
```

Comment: when i do `settings.MEDIA_ROOT(name)` then result is `'str' object is not callable` ...

Comment: The error is your clue.  setting.MEDIA_ROOT is not a function or method, it's a string.